# Rig Door of Bus

Tags: rigging

I want rig door of Bus and i am beginner in blender [image] i found this Rig and it meet what i want but ididnot understand it. can one please explaing it for me. Thanks alot

and the rig too like in this youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBPdgouJiJk

Comment: Maybe share the rig you've downloaded if you want us to explain it. Also, is the system shown of this video the same as the one you've downloaded?

Comment: unfortunately this file not available i found just image for it in this webpage https://www.artstation.com/artwork/W2a1O3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is made this way:

- Create a 3 bone armature, with *bone1_R*, *bone2_R* and *bone3_R* (the vertical one), bend a bit between bone 2 and bone 3 so that it will bend in the right direction, unparent *bone3_R*.

[image]

- Switch to *Pos*e mode, Give an *IK* constraint to *bone2_R*, with *bone3_R* as target, choose a *Chain Length* of 2.

[image]

- Give *bone3_R* a *Limit Location* constraint so that it will only move on the X axis, set the *Minimum X* and *Maximum X* values. This constraint is not absolutely necessary though, it's just to ease the manipulations.

[image]

- Create your right door object, keep your armature in *Pose* mode, select your door, then *bone2_R*, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > parent it to *bone2_R*.

[image]

- Move *bone3_R* on the X axis to test the door movement.

[image]

- In *Edit* mode, select all the bones and go in the *Armature* menu > *Symmetrize*. Now you have all your bones symmetrized and called *bone1_L* etc...

[image]

- Change the *Limit Location* values of *bone3_L* so that it fits to its position on the left.

[image]

- Create your left door object and parent it to *bone2_L*.

[image]

- In *Edit* mode, you can create a root bone and parent the right and left bones 1 and 3 to this root bone.

[image]

- To make the animation easier you can even give *bone3_L* a *Copy Location* with the *bone3_R* as target. This way you control both the doors with only one bone (*bone3_R*). If you choose to do so, it makes the *bone3_L Copy Location* useless as *bone3_L* will only move on the X axis.

[image]

- Is seems to work fine, both the doors open.

[image]

Comment: oh yes sorry, sure, done  ;)

Comment: Thanks moonboots.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works very good. In first Image you mean "bend a bit between 2 and 1" right?

Comment: exactly, bend a bit between bone 2 and bone 3 so that it will bend in the right direction

Comment: another question please, maybe you have experience in ue4. How can i get these constraint in ue4

Comment: sorry no I don't know anything about ue4   ;)

Comment: @moonboots thanks very much.